# Streaming Large Amounts of Data between Computers

Tags: c#, stream, streaming, client-server, data-stream

I'm working on a project within Unity3D in whereby I need to send large amounts of data from client computers, to a master/server computer.

Each client computer has a Kinect Sensor connected to it. *Some* of the Kinect data is to be steamed somehow to a localised master computer.

My question is, whats the best way to do this? I'm currently using a RPC network protocols in C# within Unity3D. I basically have a client Unity running in the client computers, taking data from kinect, converting it into bytes and sending it over the LAN to my server (which is picked up by another Unity program).

However, just using one client uses 10Mb/s of download/upload speed, and after about 30 seconds of streaming, my network seems like it gets bogged down and then refuses to send anymore data until I restart the client again.

I'm not too savvy on network procedures. But I'm just wondering if there is a better method to use?

Note:

- All clients and master computer are actually in the same room (so everything is local).
- From my calculations, each client needs to steam around 10Mb/s. There will most likely be around 6 clients. Meaning a total stream of 60Mb/s. Which shouldn't be a problem if I go down the Network route right? (as its all local).
- The stream doesn't necessarily have to occur within Unity3D, just as long as I can actually get the data into Unity on the Master end.
- The data itself is to be sent around ~30 times a second (which is taken into account for the '10Mb/s')

Thanks.

--- Update ---

**What Am I Doing?**

The idea is to be able to stream the 3D depth data from all the clients (that have Kinects connected) to the Master. The master is to then process all this data, and build a 3D representation of the centre of the room all the Kinects are facing (using point cloud).

- This is to be real-time (or as real time as I can get it - given the circumstances).
- I am indeed using a wired LAN (All connect through a new router with gigabit ethernet) - all localised, all within 10 feet of one another.
- The master computer is a 2.3 GHz Intel Core i7, so it should be able to receive a stream of 10Mbs.
- The 'bogged' down issue I mentioned earlier could be down to Unity's RPC system for all I know ?! :/
- I'm tempted to write a small Windows Program that will stream the Kinect Data to the Master IP - and for Unity to pick it up (somehow - I have no idea how to achieve that - it just seems more logical, right?)

Thanks.

Comment: Have you looked into any compression routines to reduce network traffic volume?  In a typical situation like you are describing, you want to process as much of the data on the local client to send the minimal amount of data back to a central server.  Seems like you are trying to do all of your processing on the server.  While this may be convenient, it's at the expense of bandwidth, which seems to be where you are hitting the wall.

Comment: Have you considered using a FTP server? I am fairly new to this kind of stuff but I think it could be useful for what you need to do.

Comment: @jdoyle1983 I haven't considered compression on the client side - however, if I do attempt this, won't this cause a delay between what the Kinect Sensor sees, and what is Rendered on the Server? I would like to try and keep delay/latency as minimal as possible.

Comment: @OliverJones Of course, but without knowing the full intent of your implementation, it's hard to make a case for latency vs. bandwidth.  That's for you to decide.  However, if you are having issues where things come to halt, then perhaps a small amount of latency could be acceptable and accounted for within your application.

Comment: @jdoyle1983 Okay thanks! I shall do some research into compression.

Comment: So to confirm - the best suggestion is indeed to carry on down the Network route?

Comment: You don't really give much detail on your set up but the first ting to say is that you should used wired connections rather than WiFi if you aren't already and if you have the option, as wired will have higher bandwidth generally and you will have less chance of interference. Assuming you are using a wired LAN, then 10MBs should definitely not bog down any single link (unless your network equipment is very, very old...). It might be that your master computer does not have the connectivity or processing power to receive the streams from all the clients so this would be worth investigating.

Comment: @Mick Thanks. Yeah Definitely wired is the way to go, for sure! But it gets bogged down via Unity FTP. I've updated my question :)